# Error cast double to Double using iReport 3.0.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How convert Double value for math operations?

I have some vars:

**totGlosaFaturaHospitalar = java.lang.Double**

and

**totFaturamentoEmpresas= java.math.BigDecimal**

```
(($V{totGlosaFaturaHospitalar}.doubleValue()/$V{totFaturamentoEmpresas}.doubleValue())-1)
```

Comment: What error did you get? Is it *textField* expression? You should post declaration of it (the part of *jrxml*)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
(($V{totGlosaFaturaHospitalar}.doubleValue()*1.0/$V{totFaturamentoEmpresas}.doubleValue())-1)
```

Cause have one double in the calcul transform all in double